# vdiskmanager for vmware workstation 12

Tags: vmware

I created a virtual system using VMWare Workstation 12 Player. I selected the hard disk type to be growable. Now I want to switch to preallocated.

I learnt from google that this can be done using `vmware-vdiskmanager.exe`. However, it seems that this utility is not bundled with the vmware player. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Some website directs me to the virtual disk development kit. I downloaded one from https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vddk/. When I use it from the command line, it says: `Failed to convert disk: Disk encoding error (0x3ebd)`.
I doubt that it is because of the mismatch of the version.

Could anybody help on how to solve this?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Were you able to solve the problem? If yes, what was the solution? Thanks.

Comment: @ulughbekula, it is not solved. Sorry I didn't notice your comment.

Comment: @ulughbekula, I didn't receive any constructive answer. I just deleted that vm and created a new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [Knowledge Base article](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1023856) has an older copy of it.  I don't know if it work for you, but at least here you can try to get a standalone version of vmware-vdiskmanager.exe.

**EDIT**

So [this](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2019259) is a more updated version from 2017 of the KB without download.  Just including for completeness